# when use rebase master or origin/master

Tags: git

I think we develop our project in a branch and when finished, we rebase it to master branch and then we can push it to repository server.

If I think wrong, tell me, and explain when we rebase to origin/master

*update:thank for ur answers, but u are misunderstood, I need to know difference of

`git rebase master`

and

`git rebase origin/master`

Comment: It will be helpful for you to read some Git manual: [Git Basics - Working with Remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) and [Merging vs. Rebasing](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want to compare `git rebase master` with `git rebase origin/master`.

The argument you give to `git rebase` is what [the `git rebase` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) calls the *upstream*.  This is not a very good name (the documentation is, in this case, not so great) but the answer *is* in there.

What `git rebase` does is to *copy* some set of commits.  Git needs two pieces of information: *which commits should it copy?* and *where should it copy them to?*  This one argument, this *upstream* as the documentation calls it, provides the answer to *both* questions.

To understand this copying process, you need to draw at least some part of the *commit graph* so that you can see which commits get copied and what happens afterward.

Drawing commit graphs is a little bit tricky, although if you practice it for a while you can get quite good at it.  To draw the graph, you need to view the commits *with* their parent linkages.  You can use `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`, which will do its own graph drawing, or use a graphical viewer like `gitk` or some Git GUIs.  (You *cannot* use GitHub's graphs as they contain the wrong information.)  If you draw them manually, it's helpful to have a whiteboard or similar.

Let's draw a quick sample graph here.  Your own graph may be different.

```
                C4   <-- feature
               /
...--C1--C2--C3   <-- master
               \
                C5--C6   <-- origin/master
```

These `Cn`s represent commits.  We say that each commit "points back" to its parent (previous) commit.  Note that the parent of a commit always comes earlier, but "earlier" doesn't always mean a lot.  Here, probably made your branch `feature` from your branch `master`, then made one commit on it.  Since then, you also ran `git fetch`, which has obtained two commits from what Git calls a *remote* named `origin`.  These two commits are now on your `origin/master`, but not on your `master`.

#### What to copy and where to copy

If at this point you run `git checkout feature` and then `git rebase master`, Git will tell you that there is nothing to do (`Current branch feature is up to date`).  If you run `git rebase origin/master`, though, it will do something.

The key as to why is, again, in the documentation.  Rebase starts out by selecting *which commits to copy* using the two-dot notation described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html):

```
master..feature
```

(the name `feature` comes from your *current branch*, the one you have checked out; the name `master` comes from your argument to `git rebase`).

This two-dot notation means: *On the commit graph, start at `feature` and work backwards through its parents, and mark all these commits green.  Then, on the same graph, start at `master` and work backwards through its parents and mark all these commits red.*

When we do this with the graph I've drawn, we mark `C4` green, then mark `C3` green, then mark `C2` green, and so on.  Commits `C5` and `C6` don't get marked at all.  Then, we mark `C3` red—this overrides its green—and mark `C2` red, and so on.  What we're left with is just `C4` in green.

This means that what `git rebase master` will do is *copy* commit `C4`.

Now, the next step is to figure out *where to copy*.  The answer is: right after whichever commit the *upstream* points to.  So this says: *Copy commit C4 to where it is right now.*  Which is pointless, so `git rebase` says there is nothing to do.

If you run `git rebase origin/master` right now, Git will mark `C4` green, and then `C3` green, and so on as before; then it will mark `C6` red, `C5` red, `C3` red, and so on.  This gives us the list of commits to copy, which once again is just commit `C4`.  We marked more commits, but the end result for *what to copy* turned out to be the same.  And then the next step is to figure out *where to copy*, and this time, it's different.

We're supposed to copy all the commits—all one of them—to come right after the one `origin/master` points-to, which is `C6`.  So we must copy commit `C4` there.

#### How Git copies commits

The main command that copies commits is `git cherry-pick`.  So, internally, `git rebase` often uses `git cherry-pick` to do the copying.  Some kinds of rebase use different commands internally, but the end result is intended to be the same.  We can just view this as a cherry-pick, anyway.

To do the copying, Git first checks out the "after" commit, `C6`.  It does so without checking out any *branch*—it checks out the raw commit instead, using what Git calls "detached HEAD" mode.  If something goes wrong during the rebase, you are left in this "detached HEAD" mode.  That's not a big deal, and if everything goes *right*, Git gets right back out of this mode, but it's worth remembering.

Anyway, so Git "detaches HEAD" and makes it point to commit C6:

```
                C4   <-- feature
               /
...--C1--C2--C3   <-- master
               \
                C5--C6   <-- origin/master, HEAD (detached)
```

and then cherry-picks `C4` to copy it.  Read [the `git cherry-pick` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) for details, but essentially, this copies the *changes* you made, by comparing `C4` vs `C3`, then makes a new commit with a copy of the *commit message* as well.  The new copy comes after the HEAD commit, which is `C6`, so it looks like this:

```
                C4   <-- feature
               /
...--C1--C2--C3   <-- master
               \
                C5--C6   <-- origin/master
                      \
                       C4A   <-- HEAD (detached)
```

The new commit is a lot like `C4`, but has a different *parent* commit: it points back to existing commit `C6`, not to `C3`.

#### After the copying

We've now finished copying all the commits we had to copy, so for its final trick, `git rebase` makes the branch name that we *were* on, i.e., `feature`, point to this last commit it copied.  In other words, it reattaches your HEAD, but at the new graph location:

```
                C4   [abandoned]
               /
...--C1--C2--C3   <-- master
               \
                C5--C6   <-- origin/master
                      \
                       C4A   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

#### What happens to the original, pre-copy, commit `C4`?

Git secretly hangs on to it for a while, but it's "gone invisible".  It has no *name* by which you can find it.  It's not on any of your branches any more!  Eventually, the things that keep it around—what Git calls *reflog entries*—expire, and Git removes it entirely through what Git calls *garbage collection*.  For a short while, though, you can "undo" a `git rebase` if you need to.

#### Branch names change—well, *move*, over time.  Commits don't.

Let's go back to the original graph, i.e., back before we ran `git rebase origin/master`:

```
                C4   <-- feature
               /
...--C1--C2--C3   <-- master
               \
                C5--C6   <-- origin/master
```

If, at this point, you run `git checkout master` and then `git merge origin/master`—or `git checkout master` and then `git pull`, which runs `git merge` for you—Git will *move* your name `master` in a "fast-forward" operation:

```
                C4   <-- feature
               /
...--C1--C2--C3
               \
                C5--C6   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

There was no need to do anything else, so Git did the least work it could get away with.  It made the name `master` point to commit `C6`, too, just like `origin/master` does.  (I've marked `master` with `HEAD` since we did a `git checkout` master to get here.)

If you *now* do the same kind of rebase you were going to do earlier, now *both names*, `master` and `origin/master`, point to *the same commit*.  So now, after `git checkout feature` to attach your `HEAD` to `feature`, `git rebase master` and `git rebase origin/master` will *do the same thing*.

Remember, the rebase operation uses the *upstream* argument to find out *what to copy* and *where to put the copies*.  That's all it uses this argument for, so if two different names point to the *same* commit, the "what to copy" and "where to copy" answers will be the same for both names.

It's when two different names point to *different* commits that you get different results.  The green-vs-red trick *may* (or may not—try this with other graphs) mean that you get the same commits *copied*, but the "where to copy" part is different, by definition.

Comment: This was so well written. Nice stuff!

Answer (score 4):

Rebase could be needed when your branch is behind and you need the changes from master. You could also use merging, but rebase is preferred by some. (Including myself)

> I need to know difference of
>
> `git rebase master`
>
> and
>
> `git rebase origin/master`

The different is to rebase on your local master, or the one of origin.
It's likely that your local master is behind origin/master, but it could be also forward or even has different histories (not recommend)

If your `master` is the same as `origin/master`, it doesn't matter which one to use.

We rebase (and branch) from `origin/master` so we don't have to update our local master. (no need to do `git pull` on the local `master` branch).

If you rebase on local master, you could do:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout myBranch
git rebase master
```

if you rebase on origin/master, you could do

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
```

so a lot shorter.

### Shorter syntax

For even shorter, you could also use "pulled rebase", that one is nicely to combine with the "origin rebase":

```
git pull origin master --rebase
```

No need to fetch then.

If you're even more lazy, you could set the rebase on by default when pulling.

Set  `git config --global pull.rebase true`, only once needed.

Then for the pulled rebase, just use

```
git pull origin/master
```

PS: Unfortunately of the inconsistent syntax (`origin/master` vs `origin master`)

Comment: I think u meant if we want to make a change and then push it,we can rebase to master and make a pull origin or rebase to origin/master and push,then don't need to pull origin??

Comment: updated my answer!

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: I had forgotten to add why fast forward merges are preferred by some, it is because there are no merge conflicts, as the branch pointer is just moved forward, instead of having to merge 2 separate copies of the code**

Rebase merge does this:

First, you have commits on your branch

[image: First image]

Merging would just move master to C1, and everything would be ok

But if someone adds a commit then it would look like this:
[image: Second image]

And the merge is no longer a fast forward merge.

Rebasing your branch off C2 changes it to this:
[image: Third image]

Which means the merge can be done as a fast forward, making sure there are no conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

I usually prefer `rebase` for small-medium changes and `merge` for large, long-standing branches.

`rebase` has the advantage of giving you a very clean commit history.

`merge` has the advantage of giving you an explicit merge commit, which means the changes to resolve merge conflicts are sectioned off by themselves.  With `merge`, if you later find a bug with the branch or you realize that you fixed a conflict in the wrong way, it is much easier to revert the merge commit and apply the necessary fixes.